# Problems using GLTexImage3D correctly

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

This is how I give the Bitmaps to OpenGL. (C#)

```
public static int Generate3DTexture( string[] names ) // file paths
{
    //basically merging the images into one vertical column of images
    MagickImageCollection allimages = new MagickImageCollection();
    foreach (string eachname in names)
        allimages.Add(new MagickImage(eachname));
    MagickImage template = new MagickImage(MagickColor.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0), MasterSize.Width, MasterSize.Height * names.Length);
    Point drawpnt = new Point(0, 0);
    foreach (MagickImage each in allimages)
    {
        template.Composite(each, drawpnt.X, drawpnt.Y, CompositeOperator.Overlay);
        drawpnt.Y += each.Height;
    }
    Bitmap merged = template.ToBitmap();
    //saving the bitmap here is confirmed to stack them vertically
    BitmapData thedata = merged.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), merged.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, WfPixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    int texId = GL.GenTexture();
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture3D, texId);
    GL.TexImage3D(TextureTarget.Texture3D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, MasterSize.Width, MasterSize.Height, names.Length, 0, GlPixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, thedata.Scan0);
    GL.GenerateMipmap(GenerateMipmapTarget.Texture3D);
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture3D, 0);
    merged.UnlockBits(thedata);
    return texId;
}
```

I found a description for how the data should be organized [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexImage3D.xml), which I interpreted to mean the images should be arranged vertically, and possibly flipped or something.

So for my test I used 2 images, on the fragment shader I apply the texture like so:

```
void main()
{
    outputColor =  texture3D(ThreeDTexture,vec3(texcoord.x, 1.0 - texcoord.y, 0));
}
```

The result is the two images merged in roughly equal proportions. That's what I would expect if I made the `vec3.z` parameter `0.5`. So I tried it with three images. It gives a 50-50 combination of the first and last images supplied (?!?!).  This is it's behavior without regard to the value I give for `vec3.z`.

I expected that parameter to be the Z axis for the images supplied. Or if I used whole numbers for it to be an index for the array of images supplied.

**EDIT:** It is the index, but projected on the range 0 through 1, like the x,y coordinates are.

Where did I go wrong?

What I'm giving to OpenGL (in order):

[image: What I'm giving to OpenGL]

The result:

[image: The result.]

**EDIT:** As Rabbid76 explains, the solution was to insert this after the call to `GL.TexImage3D`:

```
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture3D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureParameterName.ClampToEdge);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture3D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureParameterName.ClampToEdge);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture3D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapR, (int)TextureParameterName.ClampToEdge);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture wrap parameters `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`, `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R`  are by default `GL_REPEAT`.
The default parameters for the minifying function (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`) and magnification function are (`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`) are `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` respectively `GL_LINEAR`.
See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).

The combination of "REPEAT" and "LINEAR" causes, that the first voxel is mixed (interpolated) with the last voxel of a row, column, or depth-layer, if the the texture coordinate parameters, which is passed to the lookup function, is 0.0.

If you would use the wrap parameter `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, then the first and the last voxel won't become mixed, because the texture coordinate is clamped.

Note the texture coordinate of the first voxel (or texel) is `1/(2*N)` and the coordinate of the last voxel is `1 - 1/(2*N)`, where `N` is the number of voxels in a row, column or layer. Because of that the coordinate 0.0, is exactly in the middle of the first and the last voxel. `GL_REPEAT` would clamp the coordinate 0.0 to `1/(2*N)`.

Comment: Exactly right. Added the equivalent openTK code to question. Thanks